# How to upload files on AWS s3 using zend framework 2.3

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, zend-framework, amazon-s3

I am new to zend and want to upload images on Amazon S3 I am using zend framework 2.3 but unable to include [S3](https://github.com/tpyo/amazon-s3-php-class/blob/master/S3.php) class in my Controller.

```
class MessageController extends BaseController {
  public function composeAction() {

    if (!class_exists('S3')) require_once 'S3.php';

    // AWS access info
    if (!defined('awsAccessKey')) define('awsAccessKey', 'XXXXXXXXXX');
    if (!defined('awsSecretKey')) define('awsSecretKey', 'XXXXXXXXXX');

    // Instantiate the class
    $awsS3 = new S3(awsAccessKey, awsSecretKey);

    echo print_r($awsS3 ->listBuckets(), 1)."\n";

    /****
    *  Continue...
    *
    ****/
   }
}
```

Getting error:

( ! ) Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class S3 in

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the `ZendService/amazon`?

Documentation: https://zf2.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.3.1/modules/zendservice.amazon.s3.html

Use composer to add the dependencies.

and create the S3 object with:

`$s3 = new \ZendService\Amazon\S3\S3($accessKey, $secretKey);`

Comment: Yes I tried to install using composer but getting error:

Using version ^2.3 for zendframework/zendservice-amazon
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.